# Are custom hooks special functions like Function Components w.r.t. hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, react-hooks

As we know, if we use a `useState` in a `Function Component`, state does not get created every time on `re-renders` of that Function component, instead it uses existing state. See an `Example` Function component below:

```
function Example() {
  // Declare a new state variable, which we'll call "count"
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Where as when we have a `useState` in a `customHook` instead (see below), each call to "`useCustomHook`" makes a new state, which gives an idea that all custom hooks are just regular functions.

```
function useCustomHook() {
  const [cnt, setCnt] = useState(0);
  return [cnt, setCnt];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can see from the snippet below, that a `useState` call **is persistent** inside a customHook just like it works inside a regular component. You can keep track of it and even manipulate it. **It's not recreated on every hook call.**

[From React DOCS: Custom Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html)

> Custom Hooks are a convention that naturally follows from the design of Hooks, rather than a React feature.
>
> **Do I have to name my custom Hooks starting with “use”?**
>
> Please do. This convention is very important. Without it, we wouldn’t be able to automatically check for violations of rules of Hooks because we couldn’t tell if a certain function contains calls to Hooks inside of it.
>
> **Do two components using the same Hook share state?**
>
> No. Custom Hooks are a mechanism to reuse stateful logic (such as setting up a subscription and remembering the current value), but every time you use a custom Hook, all state and effects inside of it are fully isolated.
>
> **How does a custom Hook get isolated state?**
>
> Each call to a Hook gets isolated state. Because we call useFriendStatus directly, from React’s point of view our component just calls useState and useEffect. And as we learned earlier, we can call useState and useEffect many times in one component, and they will be completely independent.

```js
function App(){

  const [hookState,setHookState] = useSomeCustomHook();
  
  function updateHookState() {
    setHookState((prevState)=>prevState+1);
  }
  
  return(
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>Custom Hook State: {hookState}</div>
      <button onClick={updateHookState}>Count</button>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

function useSomeCustomHook() {
  const [hookState,setHookState] = React.useState(0);
  return ([
    hookState,
    setHookState
  ]);
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: You have only called useCustomHook once, its returned variables are part of the state of `App` Function component. My question is that `customHook definitions` do not get special treatment as `Function Component` ?

Comment: What do you mean by special treatment?

Comment: Means using existing state values, instead of creating new state, whenever function runs.

Comment: They do, it's just not shared with the state that lives in the component. Everyting is isolated. It's not exactly a component also. It's a way to share _stateful logic_ as they like to say it somewhere in the docs.